# Yii - how to access the base URL in main config

Tags: php, url, path, yii

I am working on a Yii application. I am trying to set some paths in my main config params like this:

```
// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>array(
       'paths' => array(
            'imageTemp'=> Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/files/temp-',
            'image'=> Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/files/',
            ...
        ),

        'urls' => array(
            'imageTemp'=> Yii::app()->getBaseUrl().'/files/temp-',
            'image'=> Yii::app()->getBaseUrl().'/files/',
            ...
        ),
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBaseUrl() on a non-object in ..blahblah../base/CApplication.php on line 553
```

I think I cannot use Yii::app() in config file since the app is not initialized yet here, or something like this. So, how can I replace `Yii::app()->getBaseUrl()` in the config file and get the same results?

Comment: Where exactly do you know what the web root is going to be? Normally you set this in the config file itself, no? I usually make a define or something if I have to specify the same thing more than once.

Comment: Good question :D So, should I use something like this:`"http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` or there is any other more convenient way in Yii to use instead?

Comment: webroot = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) if you really want to define it. You can also store it in alias format? "webroot.files" or something? You can getPathOfAlias() it later on in your app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, you can't use the Yii::app() methods inside the config's return array, but you can use `Yii::getPathOfAlias()` outside. Something like this might work:

```
$webroot = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot');
return array(
    ...
    'params'=>array(
        'paths' => array(
            'imageTemp'=> $webroot.'/files/temp-',
            'image'=> $webroot.'/files/',
            ...
        ),
    ),
);
```

Assuming `webroot` is defined beforehand.

As for baseUrl... I'll come back to you on that one!

[Back...]

If you need a url, it all depends where your images files are being kept, relative to the yii path, or relative to the base of the web root?

If the base of the web root, you could just use:

```
return array(
    ...
    'urls'=>array(
        'paths' => array(
            'imageTemp'=> '/files/temp-',
            'image'=> '/files/',
            ...
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: The webroot alias is created after the configuration for the application is loaded, so even if you use that call, the alias does not exist yet. This won't work.

Comment: ah, in that case, yes you can't use that method. Can you not use `$_SERVER` vars at all?

Comment: As a rule I try to avoid using anything Yii-related in the config at all. The file is used to create your application after all and you never know what will already work and what wont :) But stuff like $_SERVER and so on can be used as you please. As I already stated above, if you really need the webroot, its defined as dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']). I normally define my own "BASEDIR" in the config which is dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_) . '/../..', I like that more. But to each his own :)

Comment: @Blizz, yep on the whole I agree, although the default yii config file does have a `Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');` included in it, so it's not "bad" to use Yii params in there, just probably not advised to do it that way!

Comment: Never said it was bad not to do so, just that I try to avoid it :) I regularly set aliases in the config as well. It wouldn't have been made available as a framework level function if it was not to be used everywhere, right? :)

Comment: @Stu So, any idea to get the base url?

Comment: Masha: I never said it doesn't, I said that in your config file it's not defined yet. I looked it up in my Yii source and the definition of the alias is done about 5 lines of code after the include of the config file. Unless that is something that was changed recently.